# in JUnit test (java) How to check in a array of array with Assertj librairy?

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, junit, assertj

I want use assertj for cheking a data in array contain a other array.

```
accounts: [class AccountResource {
        resourceId: 010001781LV
        bicFi: null
        accountId: null
        name: Livret A Rosalie
        details: LIVRET A
        linkedAccount: null
        usage: PRIV
        cashAccountType: null
        product: LVA
        currency: EUR
        balances: [class BalanceResource {
            name: null
            balanceAmount: class AmountType {
                currency: EUR
                amount: 10000
            }
            balanceType: CLBD
            lastChangeDateTime: null
            referenceDate: 2018-05-31
            lastCommittedTransaction: null
        }, class BalanceResource {
            name: null
            balanceAmount: class AmountType {
                currency: EUR
                amount: 10000
            }
            balanceType: XPCD
            lastChangeDateTime: null
            referenceDate: 2018-05-31
            lastCommittedTransaction: null
        }]
        psuStatus: Account Holder
        links: null
    }
```

My 2 first tests case are OK. I filter on 'resourceId=010001781LV' and I check  account.currency=EUR. I filter on 'resourceId=010001781LV' and I check  account.balances.size()=2.

```
assertThat(halAccounts.getAccounts())
        .filteredOn(account -> account.getResourceId().equals("010001781LV"))
        .extracting(account -> account.getCurrency())
        .containsExactly("EUR");
assertThat(halAccounts.getAccounts())
        .filteredOn(account -> account.getResourceId().equals("010001781LV"))
        .extracting(account -> account.getBalances().size())
        .containsExactly(2);
```

but I want filter on 'resourceId=010001781LV' and filter on 'balances(foreach).balanceType=CLBD' and check  balanceAmount=10000.

**I try** lambda in other lambda **but I need some help**:

```
assertThat(halAccounts.getAccounts())
    .filteredOn(account -> account.getResourceId().equals("010001781LV"))
    .filteredOn(account -> account.getBalances().forEach(balance -> {
        balance.getBalanceAmount().getAmount().equals("10000");
    }))
    .extracting(balance -> balance.getBalanceAmount().getAmount())
    .contains("1000");
```

**I have this error on 2nd `filteredOn`:**

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
    - The method filteredOn(Condition<? super AccountResource>) in the type AbstractIterableAssert<ListAssert<AccountResource>,List<? 
     extends AccountResource>,AccountResource,ObjectAssert<AccountResource>> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> account) -> {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that expression inside `filterOn` should return `boolean` whereas `forEach` returns `void`.

Account id should be "DEF" and all "A" balances should have "10" value.

```
@Test
void test() {
    Account wrongAcc = new Account("ABC", Collections.emptyList());
    Account goodAcc = new Account("DEF", Arrays.asList(
            new Balance("A", "10"),
            new Balance("A", "10"),
            new Balance("B", "20")
    ));
    Account wrongBalanceAcc = new Account("DEF", Arrays.asList(
            new Balance("A", "10"),
            new Balance("A", "20"),
            new Balance("B", "20")
    ));

    List<Account> accountList = Arrays.asList(wrongAcc, goodAcc, wrongBalanceAcc);

    assertThat(accountList)
            .filteredOn(acc -> acc.getId().equals("DEF"))
            .filteredOn(acc ->
                    acc.getBalances()
                            .stream()
                            .noneMatch(balance -> balance.getType().equals("A") && !balance.getAmount().equals("10"))
            ).containsExactly(goodAcc);
}
```

Comment: thank you, your code helped me. I test with this: `assertThat(halAccounts.getAccounts()).filteredOn(account -> account.getResourceId().equals("010001781LV"))                .filteredOn(account -> account.getBalances().stream()                        .anyMatch(balance -> balance.getBalanceType().equals(BalanceStatus.CLBD))).extracting(account -> account.getBalances().stream().anyMatch(balance -> balance.getBalanceAmount().getAmount().equals("10000"))).containsOnly(true);`. is it possible to get the object `Balance` in the `containsExactly` instead of a `boolean`?

Comment: @sgrillon containsExactly will use type of a collection it was called on. So if you have a list of booleans you can compare only to boolean. If you have list of Balance, then compare to balance.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct the following code does not return a boolean ([forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) does not):

```
account.getBalances().forEach(balance -> {
    balance.getBalanceAmount().getAmount().equals("10000");
})
```

which means that it is not a valid `Predicate` to be used in

```
filteredOn(account -> account.getBalances().forEach(balance -> {
    balance.getBalanceAmount().getAmount().equals("10000");
}))
```

I believe java tries to apply `filteredOn(Condition)` which is not possible.

**Edit**

If your question is how do I filter account havinn **all** their balances amount equal to 10000 ? then you can use this `Predicate` (not tested but should be close enough to what you want):

```
account -> account.getBalances().stream()
                  .map(balance ->  balance.getBalanceAmount().getAmount())
                  .allMatch(amount -> amount.equals("10000"))
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: your answer, is not an answer. I understood that it did not work, otherwise I would not have asked this question. I was just showing that I had tried. there is little solution with flat map?

Comment: sorry but your question was not clear, hope my edit will help.

Comment: @Ivan Lymar, understood the question and responded